# Video.js Wont Play In IE

Tags: video.js

I am at a complete loss here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I can get the video to play in Chrome, Mobile devices, etc. But in IE...nothing happens when I click on the video.

Here is the link to my sandbox page: https://datacentral.esboces.org/Developers/StagingArea/Sandbox.aspx

If I open the Developers Toolbox and debug the javacode I see the following appears every time I click on the video:

LOG: Video Error [object Object]

LOG: Flash Errorsrcnotfoundexample_video_1_flash_api

Any ideas??

-Ben

Comment: doesnt work in chrome for me.  console says "No compatible source and playback technology were found."

Comment: I just tried and it works for me in Chrome.... ??? Wierd...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured out my problem, thank you to those that looked into this. The problem stemmed from the CMS that is being used. The HTML editor (By Telerik) by default takes "some" HTML tags and reformats them.

What I didn't realize was that it was taking my original code from this:

```
    <video id=example_video_2 class="video-js vjs-default-skin" preload="none" poster="getting_started_project2.png" data-setup="{}" controls="controls" width="640" height="360">
    <source src="getting_started_project2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
```

...and was changing it to this (terminating my tags prematurely):

```
    <video id=example_video_2 class="video-js vjs-default-skin" preload="none" poster="getting_started_project2.png" data-setup="{}" controls="controls" width="640" height="360" />
    <source src="getting_started_project2.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
```

I had to figure out how to disable that stupid tag reformatting and TADA...it works... I don't know how much hair I lost from pulling it out over this problem...